# Confused between modules and bundles property in RequireJS / r.js build files

Tags: requirejs

I am very confused at to what the difference is between the "bundles" property and the "modules" property in a r.js build file that might look something like:

```
({
    "allowSourceOverwrites": false,
    "preserveLicenseComments": false,
    "findNestedDependencies": false,
    "optimizeAllPluginResources": true,
    "dir":"../public/bundles",
    "baseUrl": "../public/static",
    "optimize":"none",
    "mainConfigFile": "../public/static/app/js/main.js",
    "normalizeDirDefines": "all",
    "paths" :{
        requireLib : 'vendor/require',
        jqueryUI: "empty:",
        jqueryUICSS: "empty:"
    },
    "modules": [
        {
            name: "shared",
            include: [
                'jquery',
                'async',
                'backbone'
            ],
            exclude:[]
        }
    ],
    "bundles": {
        'shared': [],
        'secondary': []
    },
    "stubModules":['text']
})
```

I am having a lot of trouble finding good information on how to create multiple bundles for a RequireJS project. When I just use the modules property and eliminate the bundles property, r.js goes looking for a file called shared.js - and I am not sure why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`r.js` *creates* bundles, but the `bundles` option is not an option that `r.js` recognizes. If you look in the [file](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/b2bcbae4529579e4edf4249ffc7c5850c19fda6b/build/example.build.js) that lists all `r.js` options, you won't find `bundles` there. If you remove it from your configuration, you'll get the same behavior.

> When I just use the modules property and eliminate the bundles property, r.js goes looking for a file called shared.js - and I am not sure why.

`r.js` looks for `shared.js` because your `modules` specifies a module named `"shared"`. `r.js` will do this *unless* you tell it that you want to create this module from scratch, and you do this by adding the `create: true` option to this module's build configuration:

```
"modules": [
    {   
        name: "shared",
        create: true, // <<<--- add this!
        include: [
            'jquery',
            'async',
            'backbone'
        ],
        exclude:[]
    }
],
```

Comment: ahh, the create:true flag, this was very confusing until you told me that. so, I assume the properties on the bundles property in the requirejs.config should in general point to the name of the modules you create?

Comment: also, my other question is: what is purpose of using the modules property if you set create:false for each module?